# How to search for string with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the below URL. I would like to get the output of all the prices on this site. The first item would be £59.

I inspected the element and found out that the html looks as below. I believe the best way would be to search for a class 'sr_gs_rackrate_total' or alternatively for a title that starts with "Price for".

How can I do this in Beautiful Soup?

```
<strong class="price scarcity_color sr_gs_rackrate_price
 anim_rack_rate  
" title="Price for 1 night £59">
<b>
<span class="sr_gs_rackrate_total">Total: </span>
£59
</b>
</strong>
```

http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaFCIAQGYAS64AQTIAQTYAQHoAQH4AQs&sid=1a43e0952558ac0ad0061d5b6523a7bc&dcid=1&checkin_monthday=23;checkin_year_month=2016-1;checkout_monthday=24;checkout_year_month=2016-1;&city=-2601889&class_interval=1&csflt=%7B%7D&dtdisc=0&group_adults=7&group_children=0&highlighted_hotels=1192837&hlrd=0&hp_sbox=1&hyb_red=0&inac=0&label_click=undef&nflt=ht_id%3D201%3B&nha_red=0&no_rooms=1&redirected_from_city=0&redirected_from_landmark=0&redirected_from_region=0&review_score_group=empty&room1=A%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA&sb_price_type=total&score_min=0&si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi&ss=London&ss_all=0&ssafas=1&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=London&ssne_untouched=London&order=price_for_two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(yourhtml)
span = soup.find('span', {'class': 'sr_gs_rackrate_total'})
b = span.parent
b.span.extract()
b.text
```

In case there is more then one span with a price in it, use

```
for span in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'sr_gs_rackrate_total'}):
  b = span.parent
  b.span.extract()
  print b.text
```

Comment: Do I need to put a for loop?

Comment: You have a bunch of items in one array. You need a for loop to go through those items one by one and print out their content